# Check if element from list_1 matches dict.key and element from list_2 matches dict.value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists and one dictionary:

```py
list_1 = ['the world', 'abc', 'bcd', 'want a car', 'hell', 'you rock']
list_2 = ['the world is big', 'i want a car', 'puppies are best', 'you rock the world']
dict_1 = {'a car':'i want a car', 'champ':'i am champ', 'you know':'you rock the world'}
```

And now, I would like to check if a key from `dict_1` *partially* matches an element from `list_1` and at the same time if a value from `dict_1` *partially* matches element from `list_2`, then it's a valid match and we have to print matched elements from `list_1`.

For example:

```
dict_1.key('a car') matches 'want a car' from list_1
```

and at the same time

```
dict_1.value('i want') matches 'i want a car' from list_2
```

therefore, this becomes a valid match.

What I have tried so far:

```py
out = [ele_1 for key, value in dict_1.iteritems() for ele_1 in list_1 if key in ele_1 for elem_2 in list_2 if value in elem_2]
print list(set(out))
```

This prints :

```
['want a car']
```

But I am not convinced that this is the best approach that I have taken and I would like to understand if I can improve my skills.

Comment: Don't expect me to update my answer, I don't see a nice way, also I really don't get it about the goal of that. Good luck

Comment: No worries. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you

```
#Let there are two list list1 and list2 and a dictonary dict
list1=[2,5,6]
list2=[3,4,5]
dict={}
dict[2]=5
dict[3]=4
#The below given code checks whether the element from list1 matches dict.key and if it matches it will print "Key is present" else "Key is not present"
if dict.get(2)!=None:
    print("Key is present")
else:
    print("Key is not present")
#The below given code checks whether the element from list2 matches dict.value and if it matches it will print "Item is present" else "Item is not present"
if 4 in dict.values():
    print("Item is present in dict.values")
else:
    print("Item is not present in dict.values")
```